# Advanced filter that compares multiple columns

Tags: excel, excel-2013

I have a table.

```
      A    |   B         |   C         |   D         |   E   
 1    ID   |   Value 1   |   Value 2   |   Value 3   |   Value 4
 2    1    |   15        |   7         |   18        |   12
 3    2    |   6         |   19        |   11        |   20
 4    3    |   24        |   10        |   12        |   9
~plus about 10,000 more
```

I trying to create an advanced filter that shows results where Value 1 > Value 2 > Value 3 > Value 4. Can't wrap my head around the criteria table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a new column F, then type this in F2

```
=AND((B2>C2),(C2>D2),(D2>E2))
```

copy and paste in the rest of the column F3..F10000

now, create a filter for column F

Comment: I think want a ',' and not a ';'.
Oh, your '<' should be '>'.

Comment: ooops, locale differences in programming (or kinda) languages! **edited**

Answer (score 2):

> shows results where Value 1 > Value 2 > Value 3 > Value 4

Here is a simple way to do it.
In cell `F2`, insert this formula

```
=IF(AND(D2>E2,C2>D2,B2>C2),"True","")
```

and copy it down.

[image]

Now simply filter it on True and copy the filtered range to a new worksheet.

Comment: Works, but it seems the if portion is superfluous and you were just a little slower than PA. :D

Comment: `you were just a little slower than PA.` Was I? I posted 2 seconds earlier than him ;)

Comment: @siddharth how can you know? you deserve the +1

Comment: doh. I guess I don't know how the site works. I though the post on top was older... I also didn't realize you could hover. Guess I learned not one but three things today!

Comment: @pa: if you hover  your mouse on the time when a post was made,  u can see the time ;-)